# Reloading on an inactive sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a meeting room reservation system on google sheets using google script. I have code written to reload the active sheet with each day so that the dates are updated. However, the inactive sheets (there are multiple sheets, one for each of the different rooms) do not reload unless you open on that sheet, or go on it then refresh. I want to code it so that the sheets automatically update even if they are not the active sheet. How would I do this? Would I use a trigger (I'm not well versed in triggers..). This is the code that I'm using right now.

```
function createDateSlots() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
   //var roomReservation = sheet.getSheetByName("Counseling Suites");
   if (sheet.getName() == "Counseling Suites" || sheet.getName() == "Interprofessional Health Suites") {
    var date = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue('SCROLL TO DATE:');
    //Creating the location for the column names 
    var startRow = 4;
    var boldRange = sheet.getRange("A" + startRow + ":H" + startRow);

    boldRange.setBackground("#b8aeae").setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false,'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    //Naming each of the columns
    sheet.getRange(startRow, dateCol).setValue('DATE');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol).setValue('Start Time:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, stopCol).setValue('Stop Time:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, resByCol).setValue('Reserved By:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, phoneCol).setValue('Phone Number:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, emailCol).setValue('Email Address:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, userCol).setValue('Faculty/ Staff/ Student');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, reasonCol).setValue('Reason for reservation:');
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to execute that for every sheet? for a sheet with a particular name? Then use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheeyByName("Counseling Suites")` to get this particular sheet. Then the trigger is a different question. Your problem now is how to get the sheet by names, the trigger might be a next step which you may or may not want to follow.

Comment: I would like to execute that for every sheet. Right now it only executes for the active sheet.

Comment: Is this an onEdit function?

Comment: @award19 did it work for you?

Comment: @Marios no, it didn't work for me. I might be doing something wrong... I'm very new to google scripts.

Comment: A new issue that I'm having (which might have something to do with this) is that the execution log shows my script times out after 30 seconds....

Comment: @award19 30 seconds is impossible for a script to run out. The quotas are 6 minutes or 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Get all the sheets with the [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) method and use a loop (in this case [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) to iterate over the sheet objects.

### Solution to execute for every sheet:

```
function createDateSlots() {
   
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
    if(sheet.getName()!='instructions'){ // put the name of the sheet you want to exclude         
    var date = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue('SCROLL TO DATE:');
    //Creating the location for the column names 
    var startRow = 4;
    var boldRange = sheet.getRange("A" + startRow + ":H" + startRow);

    boldRange.setBackground("#b8aeae").setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false,'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    //Naming each of the columns
    sheet.getRange(startRow, dateCol).setValue('DATE');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol).setValue('Start Time:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, stopCol).setValue('Stop Time:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, resByCol).setValue('Reserved By:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, phoneCol).setValue('Phone Number:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, emailCol).setValue('Email Address:');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, userCol).setValue('Faculty/ Staff/ Student');
    sheet.getRange(startRow, reasonCol).setValue('Reason for reservation:');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
  }});
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer there.

Comment: @Cooper no need to sorry. It was a couple of seconds difference. We can both have our answers here.

Comment: Well it's just that they we exactly the same code.  So no reason to have both

Comment: This code didn't work for me, it didn't throw errors, but wouldn't update the sheets.

Comment: I made a small adjustment, try again and let me know the error you are getting. @award19

Comment: @Marios this worked! Is there any way to have it exclude a sheet? I'm going to make an 'instructions' sheet to explain how to use it to the user, and I'd like to keep the formatting different on that sheet. Thank you so much for your help you're a lifesaver.